# Open another shell from cmd and execute commands from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch file which will open windows command prompt and from there it will open another shell(windchill shell). There I have to execute a command which will do some operations.

```
@echo off
start cmd.exe /k "cd D:\PTC\Windchill\bin & windchill shell"
```

Above script is opening windchill shell but I couldn't find a way to execute commands on it. I do not have much experience in this. Looking for some help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps [read this](https://www.ekito.fr/people/windchill-tips-run-windchill-shell-commands-in-batch-mode/) although the question is off topic here and not programming related, but rather _"how to"_ related.

Comment: Yes I agree about the nature of my question. That link will be very helpful for me. Thanks for that